# Multiple Sticky Headers using UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, sticky, persistent

I've been combing the web for a while trying to find out anyone who's done this before.
The default behavior is that the header of a section sticks to top until it is replaced/pushed out by the next section header.

What I'm trying to do is to have the headers aggregate on top without pushing any off-screen, and if at all possible, be able to scroll top to bottom continuously.
Is there a way I can alter the default behavior?

I haven't been able to find anything similar open-source anywhere, though I feel like I've definitely seen it used someplace (of course I have no idea where that was).

Comment: What is a `UIListview`? There is no such thing in iOS. Perhaps you mean `UITableView`.

Comment: What you are asking about can't be done with a standard `UITableView`. You need to do it yourself somehow. Of course what you want to do only makes sense if there are only a few sections.

Comment: I did mean UITableView, sorry. There would be only a few sections indeed. I wonder if anyone has any insight on how to get about doing this. Thank you for your comments!